# VS2010sp1 and SQLServer 2012 Express- A network-related or instance-

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Recently I resetup the O.S. of my Laptop due to boot sector error.

Now I have a little Problem on vs2010sp1. the database  produce error...

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Done so far;

-I resetup the sqlserver

-Enabled the tcp/ip on client protocol in (sql server configuration manager)

- on VS2010sp1 tools-> options-> data connections -> sql server intance name (blank for Default)  I set it to blank..

but still no effect HELP PLZ..

Tahnks

Comment: I've had this issue and my service wasn't started. Go to Services->SQL Server and check if it's set to automatic.

Comment: thanks for comments.. it already set to automatic. this type of error is really annoying

Comment: I also checked these 7 points: http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331 . Maybe they work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have an exception in Windows firewall for SQL Server port ( default 1433 )

Comment: hi thanks for response; I can't find the port 1433, I created new inbound rules sadly the problem still exist..

Comment: Did you check the link that @Radu Gheorghiu has supplied in his last comment ?

Comment: Also are you using default instance or a named instance ?

Comment: during the sql server setup. I choice "Named Instance" name ="SQLExpress".                                                                         here my database connection  <add name="constr" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|mysite.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: When you try to connect to the server, what do you type in the server name field ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32210/discussion-between-adel-khayata-and-user2277203)